# Separating a Gallery and HTML Pop-up on the Same Page

Tags: highslide

I have sunk hours and hours of work into trying to get Highslide working properly. Unfortunately it is so complicated that I am coming to the end of my tether with it. On the same page, I want a gallery with control buttons and also a few html iframe pop-ups with just a "close" link. I am finding it impossible to stop the control buttons appearing on the iframe pop-ups, despite having read and tried to apply all the information here, and on the Highslide website.

An example of my page is [www.littlehotels.co.uk/spain/noves.php](http://www.littlehotels.co.uk/spain/noves.php). Clicking on the big photo at the top triggers the gallery slideshow. Clicking the Location Map or Nearest Airport icons triggers the iframe popup.

Can anyone guide me to a solution before I give up and spend yet more hours tailoring a different package to my site? I will be eternally grateful. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you haven't set `slideshowGroup`, so your options in `hs.addSlideshow` are affected to all slides. See [slideshowGroup](http://highslide.com/ref/hs.slideshowGroup) and [addSlideshow](http://highslide.com/ref/hs.addSlideshow) references.

So your options should look that way:

```
hs.addSlideshow({
    slideshowGroup: ['group1', 'group2'], // here
    interval: 3500,
    repeat: true,
    useControls: true,
    fixedControls: "fit",
    overlayOptions: {
        className: "text-controls",
        opacity: .75,
        position: "bottom center",
        offsetX: 0,
        offsetY: 10,
        hideOnMouseOut: true
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you Pawel. Unfortunately, I gave up on Highslide and I am using Floatbox now. That was much clearer to understand and set up, and indeed I now have it all set up and running on my website.